# Detecting System Startup Event

Tags: windows, delphi, delphi-2010

I would like to execute a procedure that should be fired only upon windows system startup, and startup here does not mean program startup. Is there anything that I can do to trigger my procedure. If possible, i would like to avoid messing with the registry. I am using delphi 2010.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many options, but all will involve settings that require admin rights.  These options include:

1. Put your routine in a service that is set to start automatically. This will start up when the system starts up and before any user has logged on.
2. Add an entry to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`. This will execute when an interactive user logs on.
3. Add a scheduled task with an appropriate trigger, e.g. `At startup`.

Comment: @user I know. That's why I said that it runs when an interactive user logs on. That may actually be fine for OP. Especially if the app function that OP wants to run requires the context provided by a logged on user.

Comment: Do you have an example code I could look at somewhere? I am aware that setting the exe file to load on startup but it seems that the options you outlined will just load the exe and it won't know if it was triggered by a user double clicking a shortcut or system startup. There is a difference between program startup and system(windows) startup and I am interested only in the latter.

Comment: If you want different behaviour when invoked at system startup then you can just set up your scheduled task, say, to pass a command line argument to indicate that it is being called at startup.